# $a,b,c>0,a+b+c=21$ prove that $a+\sqrt{ab} +\sqrt[3]{abc} \leq 28$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, contest-math

$a,b,c>0,a+b+c=21$ prove that $a+\sqrt{ab} +\sqrt[3]{abc} \leq 28$

I have tried to use AM-GM inequality, but get no result as follows:
$$a+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt[3]{abc}\leq a+\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$

Comment: Source of the problem, please?

Comment: Equality, by the way, is obtained when $a=16$, $b=4$, $c=1$.

Comment: How to prove it or how to get it. it's a problem in a book for Mathematics Contest.

Comment: What book, please? What page?

Comment: 蔡玉书《数学奥林匹克不等式证明方法和技巧》,a exercise.

Comment: Hmm. Is there anything in there that might give a clue as to the method to use? Does the book give a source for the problem?

Comment: could you give me a clue. I could try it myself. nothing in the book.

Comment: related to 2^n? I find $16=2^4,4=2^2,1=2^0$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$a+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt[3]{abc}=a+\frac{\sqrt{4ab}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{64abc}}{4}\le a+\frac{a+4b}{4}+\frac{a+4b+16c}{12}=\frac{4(a+b+c)}{3}=28$

Comment: Nice. Small typo, missing the $c$ under the cube root.

Comment: Year.I've edited it. Thanks.

Comment: and also the result is equal to 28, not to 21.

Comment: Thx.I have understand more about the application of the AM-GM equality.