# How to prove $a+b+c+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}+\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge 7\sqrt[7]{\frac{abc(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)(a+b+c)}{24}}$?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a,b,c\ge 0,$ then prove $$a+b+c+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}+\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge 7\sqrt[7]{\frac{abc(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)(a+b+c)}{24}}$$
I found a problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714101/how-prove-this-inequality-fraca-sqrtab-sqrt3abc-sqrt4abcd4-le?noredirect=1) and try to use AM-GM but it didn't work.

By exponential, it leads to very complicated things.

Is there nice proof like AM-GM, ...?

All comment and answer is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly did you get when do exponential ? Show it clearly, I'll post my proof by AM0GM

Comment: @TATAbox Are you kidding ?

Comment: I meant it seriously

Comment: @TATAbox can you post it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof.**

Firstly, we'll prove $$\left[(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{c})\right]^4\ge 512abc(a+b)(b+c)(c+a).\tag{*}$$
Indeed, by AM-GM $$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^4=(a+b+2\sqrt{ab})^2\ge 8\sqrt{ab}(a+b).$$Multiplying similar inequalities, the $(*)$ is proven.

Now, apply $(*)$ and AM-GM as
\begin{align*}
    7\sqrt[7]{\frac{abc(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)(a+b+c)}{24}}=&7\left[\sqrt[3]{abc}.\left(\sqrt[6]{\frac{abc(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{8}}\right)^4.\frac{a+b+c}{3}.\sqrt[3]{\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{8}}\right]^{\frac{1}{7}}\\&\le \sqrt[3]{abc}+\sqrt[3]{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{b})^2(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{c})^2}+\frac{a+b+c}{3}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{8}}\\&\le \frac{a+b+c}{3}+\frac{a+b+c}{3}+\sqrt[3]{abc}+\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{c})}{3}\\&=a+b+c+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}+\sqrt[3]{abc}.
\end{align*}
Hence, the proof is done. Equality holds at $a=b=c.$

Comment: What did you motivate to prove $(*)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The first step may be the following AM-GM.
$$LHS\geq7\sqrt[7]{\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3\left(\frac{\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc}}{3}\right)^3\sqrt[3]{abc}}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$8(a+b+c)^2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc})^3\geq243(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2},$$ but my proof of this statement is not nice.

Comment: Did you check the last inequality ?

Comment: Yes, it's true. I proved it and I am looking for a nice proof.

Comment: @Dragonboy Michael Rozenberg's last inequality is right,because it is equivalent to
$$
\frac{1}{386}\sum (a-b)^{2}(3088a^6b^3+3396a^5b^4+25578a^5b^3c+3396a^4b^4c+3088a^3b^6+25578a^3b^5c+5196ac^6(a-b)^2+41b^2c(c-a)^4(a-b)^2+5196bc^6(a-b)^2+41bc^2(c-a)^4(a-b)^2+708c^7(a-b)^2)
+\frac{1}{386}\sum a(a^2-bc)(6484a^3b^2c+6484a^3bc^2+1088ab(b-c)^4+1088ac(b-c)^4+159(b-c)^6)+\frac{1290}{193}\sum a(a^3-bc^2)^2(b-c)^4+\frac{1290}{193}\sum a(a^3-b^2c)^2(b-c)^4\ge 0
$$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Did you prove it by $uvw$ ?

Comment: @Pesilk How may I learn about program from you ?